# A (not so?) simple question about differential forms

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

Let $M^n$ be a compact orientable manifold and let $\omega$ be a $(n-1)$-form in $M^n$. I want to show that there is $p\in M$ such that $(d\omega)_p=0$.

Can somebody help me, please ? Thanks :)

Comment: Wouldn't $M = [0,1]$, $\omega(x) = x$ provide a counterexample for manifolds with boundary?

Comment: yes, you're right. I forgot to write one thing that I only noticed now on the exercise. I'll edit my question. thank you very much for your comment :)

Comment: I'm sorry Daniel. I also thought that $M^{n}$ means a product, that's why I assumed that I was misunderstanding the question, regarding the non-emptiness of the boundary. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Use the Stokes formula for integrals.

> Well, suppose not. Then $\mathrm{d} \omega$ is a nowhere-vanishing differential $n$-form, so one of $\alpha = \mathrm{d} \omega$ or $\alpha = -\mathrm{d} \omega$ is a volume form. (I assume $M$ is connected.) But then $\int_{M} \alpha > 0$, contradicting the Stokes formula $\int_{M} \mathrm{d} \omega = \int_{\partial M} \omega = 0$ (because $\partial M = \emptyset$).

Comment: [The funny thing is](http://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/551943/1)

Comment: I suppose that i have to say that $M$ is a manifold WITH boundary when i want to consider that case ? That's why I made this confusion

Comment: If it's that the case, I just lost some several hours in this detail. Anyway, I edited the question from $M$ to $M^{n}$, since it's like this in my book. Is it a typo ? I mean, where did I use the compactness of the product $M^{n}$ if it's not a typo? Im sorry for all these confusions. And thanks for the help

Comment: The Stokes formula is for compactly-supported differential forms. For instance, the open interval $(0, 1)$ has a function (= 0-form) whose derivative is nowhere vanishing, but the Stokes formula is inapplicable here because it is not compactly-supported.

Comment: Also, $M^n$ just means that you are considering an $n$-dimensional manifold. It does _not_ always mean product.

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! Thank you ! I just lost hours in this simple problem because first, I assumed we could have non empty border - for which Daniel Fischer gave a counterexample in the comments - and then, I assumed it means a product.